# Bing map scraping target did not found data

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

i am using local scraper to extract restaurant data from all over the US, and my problem is when i use scrap target select  Bing map it is show 0 business result found. while if i choose yelp scrap target then the hundreds of record found and scrap all the record successfully, why bing map scrap target is not found any result.

Comment: could you share some code, or what kind of requests you are doing?

Comment: keyword is resturant, and location selected is 32118, FL,US